# How to store and query hex values in mysqldb

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, escpos

I want to use a thermal printer with raspberry pi. I want to receive the printer vendor id and product id from mysql database. My columns are of type `varchar`.

My code is

```
import MySQLdb
from escpos.printer import Usb
db= MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT,user=USER, passwd=PASSWORD, db=database)
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = ("select * from printerdetails")
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()
db.close()
for row in result:
    printer_vendor_id = row[2]
    printer_product_id = row[3]
    input_end_point = row[4]
    output_end_point = row[5]
print printer_vendor_id,printer_product_id,input_end_point,output_end_point
Printer = Usb(printer_vendor_id,printer_product_id,0,input_end_point,output_end_point)
Printer.text("Hello World")
Printer.cut()
```

but it doesnot work. the id's are string. print command shows 0x154f 0x0517 0x82 0x02.in my case

```
Printer = Usb(0x154f,0x0517,0,0x82,0x02)
```

works fine.How could I store the same id's to the database and use them to configure the printer

Comment: You are fetching data from a table called `printerdetails` and saying "it doesn't work". But you haven't shown us your data. *The id's are string* is not enough detail. What does the result of `print row` look like? And why are you creating an instance of `Usb` from the last row in the table?

Comment: I edited my code. hope it is clear now. different printer will have different id's. so i just want to change the database from an interface. is there any other way to automatically detect the id's? I want to use different printer in the same software one at a time. @ BoarGules

Comment: *print command shows 0x154f 0x0517 0x82 0x02* Not exactly. If you `print` a list or a tuple you will see brackets, the commas and maybe quotes. Your problem is translating what is in `row`, but to help you with that I need to know *exactly* what is in it. Just cut and paste it off your screen as the `print` statement shows it and format it in your question as code.

Comment: If i write print result then it shows (('0x154f', 1303L, '0x82', '0x02'),) and if i write print printer_vendor_id,printer_product_id,input_end_point,output_end_point then it shows 0x154f 1303 0x82 0x02. In database the printerdetails table fields are declared as varchar. @BoarGules

Comment: If i write print result then it shows (('0x154f', '0x0517', '0x82', '0x02'),) and if i write print printer_vendor_id,printer_product_id,input_end_point,output_end_point then it shows 0x154f 0x0517 0x82 0x02. In database the printerdetails table fields are declared as varchar. @BoarGules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your call to `Usb` is expecting integers, which works if you call it like this

```
Printer = Usb(0x154f,0x0517,0,0x82,0x02)
```

but your database call is returning tuples of hexadecimal values stored as strings. So you need to convert those strings to integers, like this:

```
for row in result:
    printer_vendor_id = int(row[2],16)
    printer_product_id = int(row[3],16)
    input_end_point = int(row[4],16)
    output_end_point = int(row[5],16)
```

Now if you do

```
print printer_vendor_id,printer_product_id,input_end_point,output_end_point
```

you will get

```
(5455, 1303, 130, 2)
```

which might look wrong, but isn't, which you can check by asking for the integers to be shown in hex format:

```
print ','.join('0x{0:04x}'.format(i) for i in (printer_vendor_id,printer_product_id,input_end_point,output_end_point))

0x154f,0x0517,0x0082,0x0002
```

I should point out that this only works because your database table contains only one row. `for row in result` loops through all of the rows in your table, but there happens to be only one, which is okay. If there were more, your code would always get the last row of the table, because it doesn't check the identifier of the row and so will repeatedly assign values to the same variables until it runs out of data.

The way to fix that is to put a `where` clause in your SQL `select` statement. Something like

```
"select * from printerdetails where id = '{0}'".format(printer_id)
```

Now, because I don't know what your database table looks like, the column name `id` is almost certainly wrong. And very likely the datatype also: it might very well not be a string.

Comment: thank you. my problem solved. your answer is great. but one thing  printer_vendor_id = ','.join('0x{0:04x}'.format(int(row[2],16))). print printer_vendor_id shows 0,X,1,5,4,f

Comment: @AkashNil If you only want to format `row[2]` then do this: `printer_vendor_id = '0x{0:04x}'.format(int(row[2],16))`. The call to `join()` in the answer is formatting 4 fields at once and stringing them together with commas. Don't use it if you only want to format one field. What happens then is that `join()` takes the value you expect, `'0x154f'`, picks it apart and strings it together with commas, giving `'0,x,1,5,4,f'` (with a lowercase `x`).